# Can not show remote svg file in Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

In my android app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.qoqa:glide-svg:2.0.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
```

in my activity:

```
import com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView;
import com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.InfiniteScrollAdapter;

    serviceUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
        serviceUrls.add("https://www.some_host.md/frontend/images/map/services/service-wi_fi.svg");
        serviceUrls.add("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/44444?s=48x48&d=identicon");
        discreteScrollView = findViewById(R.id.picker);
        InfiniteScrollAdapter wrapper = InfiniteScrollAdapter.wrap(new AgentServiceAdapter(serviceUrls));
        discreteScrollView.setAdapter(wrapper);
```

in xml

```
<com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
                       android:id="@+id/picker"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       app:dsv_orientation="horizontal" />
```

here adapter:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String serivceURL =data.get(position);
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(serivceURL)
                .into(holder.image);
    }
```

as result success show only second image, but first (**SVG**) not show

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of loading remote svg using Glide.
There is library for loading remove SVG.
Please follow this link.
https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/SVGImageView.html
https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code is useful for you.

1. Add this dependency in **build.gradle**

   `implementation 'com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'`
2. Now start working in **MainActivity.java**

   `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivimage);`

   `String url= "https://your_url/banking.svg"`
     `GlideToVectorYou.init().with(this).load(Uri.parse(url),image);`